# Regex match Array words with dash

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match some keywords in the url

```
var parentURL = document.referrer;

var greenPictures = /redwoods-are-big.jpg|greendwoods-are-small.jpg/;

var existsGreen = greenPictures.test(parentURL);
```

var existsGreen turns true when it finds greendwoods-are-small.jpg but also when it finds small.jpg

What can i do that it only turns true if there is exactly greendwoods-are-small.jpg?

Comment: What is the regex you are using?

Comment: Be aware that `.` will match any character. If you want an actual full-stop use `\.`.  (The exception is when used with a range, e.g. `[,.-]`)

Comment: Your current regex: `/redwoods-are-big.jpg|greendwoods-are-small.jpg/` does not match (find) `small.jpg`, so there is something else going on in your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^` to match the beginning of a string and `$` to match the end:

```
var greenPictures = /^(redwoods-are-big.jpg|greendwoods-are-small.jpg)$/;

var existsGreen = greenPictures.test(parentURL);
```

But of cause the `document.referrer` is not equal ether `redwoods-are-big.jpg` or `greendwoods-are-small.jpg` so i would match `/something.png[END]`:

```
var greenPictures = /\/(redwoods-are-big\.jpg|greendwoods-are-small\.jpg)$/; // <-- See how I escaped the / and the . there? (\/ and \.)
var existsGreen = greenPictures.test(parentURL);
```

Comment: Remember `.` is an any-character match

Comment: His current regex does not match `small.jpg` either, so it is perhaps something else iffy there as well.

Comment: @freefaller good point. But it would be really unlikely that a referrer would be `...../greenwoods-are-smallXjpg` :)

Comment: True, but still better to be literal

Answer (score 0):

Dashes does not have any special meaning outside character sets, e.g.:

```
[a-f], [^x-z] etc.
```

The characters with special meaning in your regexp is `|` and `.`

```
/redwoods-are-big.jpg|greendwoods-are-small.jpg/
```

- `|` denotes either or.
- `.` matches any character *except* the newline characters `\n` `\r` `\u2028` or `\u2029`.

In other words: *There is something else iffy going on in your code.*

More on [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

---

Pages like these can be rather helpful if you struggle with writing regexp's:

- [regex101](http://regex101.com/#javascript) ([with sample](http://regex101.com/r/iK9pK3))
- [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html)
- [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/)
- [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/)
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/(redwoods-are-big|greendwoods-are-small)\.jpg/i
```

I used the `i` flag for ignoring the character cases in `parentURL` variable.

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/aI4yJ6